# Como chamar os dados de uma dictlist para dentro do código em forma de CheckButton em python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, dicionário

Reformulando tudo, criei um novo arquivo do zero chamado "dict_list_codigopenal.py", ele é responsável por pegar o arquivo "cdp.csv" e ler como planilha, transformando em uma dict list. Contudo, eu preciso muito criar uma interface gráfica disto com o Tkinter. Quero saber como chamar os dados de uma dictlist para dentro do outro código em forma de CheckButton? Por exemplo, todos os checkbuttons ligados pelos "Artigos" do código penal.

Segue os códigos abaixo:

dict_list_codigopenal.py:

```
import csv
import json

def exportar():
    with open('cdp.csv', encoding="utf8",mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        infracoes = list()
        for row in csv_reader:
            infracoes.append(row)
#        print(json.dumps(infracoes, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8").decode("utf8"))
    return infracoes

infracoes = exportar()
```

central_cp_inova.py:

```
import dict_list_codigopenal
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import json

def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()

# start of GUI code
root = Tk()
root.title('Sistema de Código Penal - Cidade iNova')
root.resizable(0,0)

# start of Notebook (multiple tabs)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
notebook.pressed_index = None

# Child frames
Container1 = Frame(notebook)
Container1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
Container2 = Frame(notebook)
Container2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# Create the pages
notebook.add(Container1, text='Infrações')
notebook.add(Container2, text='Calcular')

canvas1 = Canvas(Container1, width=1200, height=450)
scroll = Scrollbar(Container1, command=canvas1.yview)
canvas1.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1400))
canvas1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas2 = Canvas(Container2, width=1200, height=450)
scroll = Scrollbar(Container2, command=canvas2.yview)
canvas2.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,100,1000))
canvas2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

frame1 = Frame(canvas1, width=800, height=450)
canvas1.create_window(300, 700, window=frame1)

frame2 = Frame(canvas2, width=800, height=450)
canvas2.create_window(200, 140, window=frame2)

# Main Frame

#Close Application Button
def quit(root):
    root.destroy()


ttk.Button(root, text="Fechar Aplicativo", command=lambda root=root:quit(root)).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = print(json.dumps(dict_list_codigopenal.infracoes, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8").decode("utf8"))

    mylabel = Label(frame1, text=dict_list_codigopenal.infracoes.get()).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive que fazer algo similar recentemente. O que você precisa é atrbuir uma variável ao seu CheckButton e depois você pode alterar o valor dela:

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
checkvar1 = tk.IntVar(root)
tk.Checkbutton(root, text='text', var=checkvar1).pack()
checkvar1.set(1)
root.mainloop()
```

use o `.set()` pra alterar o valor da variável sendo 1 para marcar o botão e 0 para desmarcar. Você vai precisar de uma variável pra cada CheckButton e é importante que essas variáveis possam ser acessadas durante todo o código, como variáveis globais ou de objeto.